# Adding a Notify signal to a Qt property at runtime?

Tags: .net, qt, com, qml, qaxobject

I have some Qt properties and signals that are generated at runtime and I want to link them as if it were declared using the `Q_PROPERTY` macro. Is it possible?

**Why I'm trying to do this:** I made a COM component in C# that I am consuming in Qt using `QAxObject`. When I load the COM component at runtime, my COM properties get automatically converted to Qt properties and my COM property changed events to Qt signals. I want to link the Qt properties to their corresponding onChanged signals.

Looking at the `QAxBase` code, it looks like Qt would automatically do what I want if my COM component supported the `IPropertyNotifySink` interface, but from what I could tell (with much research and trial and error) it's not possible to do so from C# .NET.

Comment: That sounds familiar but I cannot answer as you ask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987953/document-completed-signal-inside-qt-using-qaxwidget/48011309#48011309

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I need. All of my signals and slots connections work fine. It's just a matter of adding a notify signal to a property. I know this is typically done through the moc file, but I'm hoping there is a dynamic way of doing it.

Comment: I mean my answer with activexEventHandler. That Qt COM wrapping is so buggy and since I intensively worked on it like 3 years ago still may be not fixed but you can tap in the signal source directly.

Comment: Seems to work pretty well for me. No issues with ActiveQt directly. My issues now are with .NET and/or the core Qt Meta-Object system.

Comment: Will you get a signal for the property value change? That is a question and that what I talk about. That is Qt side which is buggy.

Comment: Yes, I get a signal for property changes. The signals are emitted when the corresponding C# COM event is fired.

Comment: So, I described the mechanism for that with which you'd be able to create specific "fixed" signal for that type of property. I doubt you will find the solution otherwise. I myself was frustrated with QAx* stuff for a while.